# How can a Bard persuade a lot of NPCs to join their harem?

Tags: dnd-5e, romance

We're playing 5e. My max Charisma 3rd level Minotaur Bard asked me how he would go about creating a harem for himself out of NPC's. He was asking me about just rolling charisma for everyone, and I had to explain to him that charisma rolls might sway a conversation, but they're not god powers. They don't just make someone fall in love with you.

I was wondering, are there any **rule based** powers or items that would make a huge amount of people fall in love or at least have a great admiration for him?

By the way, I'm not sure what he plans to do with this.. So I sort of want to see how it goes.... Call it a hunch.

Comment: I made a edit to the title, and added some emphasis to your question to help it not look like a suggestion-generation Q. Please check that I didn't mess anything up, and call me out or edit further if I did.

Comment: This question becomes really bizarre when you consider that traditionally a harem is a place in a household which is restricted to access by family members and is where the females (wives and concubines) of the house usually live. Building a part of a house out of NPCs is possible, but is likely going to involve a lot of evil and/or nightmare fodder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go level by level for bardic mind control spells. There are other spells from other classes, but none have any especially different effects.

Level 1. [Charm Person.](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Charm%20Person#content) which allows you to make temporary acquaintance with someone.

Level 2. [Suggestion.](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Suggestion#content)  This spell lets you suggest an appropriate action to someone. [Calm emotions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/calm-emotions) allows you to reduce people's anger that your bard is using magic to coerce people into sex.

Level 3 spells are pretty low on useful spells for manipulating people into sex, but there is one useful one called [Fast Friends](https://connors-personal-dnd-5e.fandom.com/wiki/Fast_Friends) Which allows quickly befriending people.

Level 4 doesn't have any notably useful spells for compelling people to love you.

Level 5 does have several. [Geas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas) lets you impose a long term command on a person, [modify memory](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/modify-memory) helps your character establish that rather than being a rapist they are a friend.

Level 6 has a useful spell, [Mass Suggestion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-suggestion) which can force multiple people to take loving actions.

In terms of magical items, the [Philter of Love](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Philter%20of%20Love#content) forces people to love you.

That said, there is an easier way. Rather than using magic to coerce innocent people to love them or admire them and then raping them, they could simply hire prostitutes. This both reduces the need to roleplay what they are up to, and provides a less creepy way to have it on the table.

Comment: What is a reasonable way to use *suggestion* to do this? The limitations on that spell seem unlikely to work. If that's your point that they wouldn't work, it may be better to state that clearly.

Comment: Let's caution the use of love magic or we are getting into dangerous territory

Comment: "We're playing 5e. My max Charisma 3rd level Minotaur Bard asked me how he would go about creating a harem for himself out of NPC's." The player didn't ask how to make people fall in love, they asked about creating a harem. Making people perform lovingly is likely equal to actual love in the player's eyes.

Likewise, the question was about a spell to make a lot of people join their harem.

Comment: @NepeneNep That’s a pretty good listing of Bard spells that might be useful for this task, but what about magic items? IIRC previous editions of DND had love potions.

Comment: I added a dnd 5.0 love potion, thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score -4):

## Why not just talk to them?

The bard has max charisma. That is extremely charismatic.

5e doesn't really explain what abilitiy scores mean, but [pathfinder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/) says 20 charisma is:

> Life of the party, able to keep people entertained for hours

It's probably similar in 5e, since 20 is the max you can get through normal means. It is the maximum charisma that a human can achieve without magic. They are probably very likable and great at persuading people to do things. It's entirely possible they could engineering a situation where people willingly join their harem without the need for magic or trickery.

Here are some suggested lines to get your player started:

- Are you French because Eiffel for you.
- Are you religious?
  Cause you’re the answer to all my prayers.
- Hey, tie your shoes! I
  don’t want you falling for anyone else.
- I must be a snowflake, because I've fallen
  for you.
- If you were a steak you would be well done.